# What is the purpose of adding chars to get an ASCII value?

Tags: java, char, ascii

When testing this (with the below code), the ASCII value for `char 'a'` is **10**, and the ASCII value for `char 'b'` is **11**. *However*, when concatenating `char 'a'` and `char 'b'`, the result is **195**.

There must be an error in my logic and/or understanding here... I *do* understand that chars cannot be concatenated as a String, but what would the ASCII int value of **195** then represent?

*And what would be the usage of such a result?*

---

Here is my code:

```
public class Concatenated
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char char1 = 'a';
        char char2 = 'b';

        String str1 = "abc";

        String result = "";
        int intResult = 0;
        Concatenated obj = new Concatenated();

        // calling methods here
        intResult = obj.getASCII(char1);
        System.out.println("The ASCII value of char \"" + char1 + "\" is: " + intResult + ".");

        intResult = obj.getASCII(char2);
        System.out.println("The ASCII value of char \"" + char2 + "\" is: " + intResult + ".");

        result = obj.concatChars(char1, char2);
        System.out.println(char1 + " + " + char2 + " = " + result + ".");

        result = obj.concatCharString(char1, str1);
        System.out.println("The char \"" + char1 + "\" + the String \"" + str1 + "\" = " + result + ".");
    } // end of main method

    public int getASCII(char testChar)
    {
        int ans = Character.getNumericValue(testChar);

        return ans;
    } // end of method getASCII

    public String concatChars(char firstChar, char secondChar)
    {
        String ans = "";
        ans += firstChar + secondChar; // "+=" is executed last

        return ans; // returns ASCII value
    } // end of method concatChars

    public String concatCharString(char firstChar, String str)
    {
        String ans = "";
        ans += firstChar + str;

        return ans;
    } // end of method concatCharString
} // end of class Concatenated
```

---

...the result printed to screen is as follows:

```
The ASCII value of char "a" is: 10.
The ASCII value of char "b" is: 11.
a + b = 195.
The char "a" + the String "abc" = aabc.
```

---

**--  EDIT :   --**

As @Marko Topolnik has pointed out below, the method `getASCII` should be changed to this to return the correct ASCII value (and **not** the UNICODE value):

```
public int getASCII(char testChar)
{
    // int ans = Character.getNumericValue(testChar); ...returns a UNICODE value!
    int ans = testChar;

    return ans;
} // end of method getASCII
```

I haven't changed the above code to reflect this, for posterity sake.

Comment: Your method is misnamed. It doesn't concatenate, it adds values together.

Comment: Ah, correct @EJP. Thanks for pointing that out. However, I have not changed my code because an answer below is referencing my incorrect method name of `concatChars`, which should be named something like `addChars` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Character.getNumericValue()` returns the int value that the specified Unicode character represents.
According to the `getNumericValue()` Javadocs: "The A tp Z letters both in uppercase and lowercase have numeric values from 10 through 35. This is independent of the Unicode specification, which does not assign numeric values to these char values."

However, when you add them in the `concatChars()` method, the 2 values that are added are the ASCII values (97 + 98).

Comment: This is a wrong explanation. All ASCII chars have the exact same value in Unicode. Specifically, Unicode code point 10 is definitely not the char *a*.

Comment: I have corrected the mistake with the Unicode vs. ASCII. Other than that I don't see a reason why my answer is incorrect. So, please explain the down-votes and the comment about the wrong explanation.

Comment: Yes, now the downvotes could be removed. However, the answer, when it was still incorrect, did get 5 undeserved upvotes.

Comment: I cannot up-vote my own answer. On the other side, it was providing the answer, with 2 wrong words included.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Dan! So, what would be the point of adding either UNICODE or ASCII values from chars? What does the sum represent in relation to the original char values?

Comment: The sum means basically nothing, it's like the sum of 2 int values.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Dan. So, there is only a usage for interpreting chars as int values, and not for doing Math with. It was confusing me, because I discovered this nature of chars by adding them.

Answer (score 5):

You are calling the wrong method: `getNumericValue` interprets the char as a digit. For example, a hex digit `A` has the value of 10.

What you should do instead is simply use the value of your char directly. Cast it to an `int`, for example.

Comment: Thanks @Marko! So, I have changed this line in the method `getACII` -- `int ans = Character.getNumericValue(testChar);` ...to -- `int ans = testChar;`. This is producing the result that makes sense with the returned value from the `concatChars` method -- **97** + **98** = **195**. So, what does **195** then represent in ASCII? And what is the purpose for getting such a result?

Comment: Also, it is interesting to me that to cast a `char` to an `int` seems to be implicit  --  `int ans = testChar;` is *correct*, whereas `int ans = int(testChar);` would be *incorrect* and does not compile.

Comment: Is JavaScript by any chance your first language? The cast syntax in Java is `(int)testChar`. But yes, in many situations the cast will be implicitly done because it's a *widening* cast.

Comment: As for your first comment here, `public String concatChars(char firstChar, char secondChar) { return "" + firstChar + secondChar; };`

Comment: Ah, I had the parentheses wrong, thanks for pointing that out @Marko! Yes, Javascript is my first language. And yes, concatenation of chars to String with the empty String.